# Visualize distances to reference point, partially preserving pairwise relative distances

Tags: data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, distance, high-dimensional

I have a high-dimensional dataset. I want to visualize the distance from each point $S_i \in S$ to a reference point $p$, while preserving the relative distances of points in $S$ to one another as much as possible.

I envisioned the following transformation to create a 2-dimensional visualization. Let $S_i'$ and $p'$ be the projection of $S_i$ and $p$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$, respectively.

$p'=(0, 0),$

$S_i' = (\lVert S_i - p \rVert, \theta_i),$

where $\theta$ is chosen to minimize the sum over $i$ of the cost function $J_i$, where

$J_i = \frac{\sum\lVert S_i - S_j \rVert}{\sum\sum{\lVert S_k - S_j \rVert}} - \frac{\sum\lVert S_i' - S_j' \rVert}{\sum\sum{\lVert S_k - S_j \rVert}}$

One condition under which I see this failing is if the distances between some points are much larger than the distances from others, even though both are very far from the reference point.

My questions are:

- Under what conditions (if any) would this visualization achieve my goal?
- Is there a simpler way to visualize the same thing?
- Is this method similar (or identical) to an existing method?
- Is there a tractable way to minimize the cost function?

Comment: It sounds like you may want something like *multidimensional scaling* (MDS).

Comment: I just looked it up and that seems right. I can focus on the reference point by re-centering so that it's at (0, 0). My worry is that points may cluster in particular directions. I could plot coordinate 1 as radius and coordinate 2 as theta, but that would distort the measure. Is there a variant on MDS, or a transformation of the output, that would minimize distortion when using re-centered polar coordinates?

Comment: That I don't know, sorry